# A long running transaction with Feign Retryer holds the connection

Tags: java, spring-boot, jdbc, spring-transactions, hikaricp

I am using Feign Retryer with a long-running transaction. It's holding a JDBC connection which I want to release.

I tried to close the connection, but it also commit a transaction, and Retryer is not invoked anymore.

Is there a way to release the connection for the time of `Thread.sleep`()?

```
public void continueOrPropagate(RetryableException exception) {
    doSomething();
    if (attempts()) {
        throw exception;
    }
    Thread.sleep(500000);
}
```

Comment: In [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2458419/is-there-something-like-a-long-running-offline-transaction-for-nhibernate-or-a) they write about something with NHibernate and DisconnectedState (which is what I believe you want). Unfortunately it relates to .NET. I cannot find anything like this for Java.